# Is it safe to inject the Hangfire BackgroundJobClient as Transient?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I have a .NET 7 project that once a day creates a job that creates other jobs. The main job exists in a service, and the sub jobs each have their own services. Is it ok to inject the IBackgroundJobClient interface that has been set up as a Transient service? I notice that in the comments for the client it says to "Please create a new instance of a state class for each operation", I'm not sure if it applies to the "Create" method of the client.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBackgroundJobClient, BackgroundJobClient>();

public MainJobService(IBackgroundJobClient client)
{
    public void CreateJob() {
        client.Create<ISubJobService>(myInterface => myInterface.CreateSubJobs());
    }
}

public SubJobService(IBackgroundJobClient client)
{
    public void CreateSubJobs() {

        for (int x; x <10; x++)
        {
            client.Create<IJobService>(myInterface => myInterface.CreateJob());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you could include some code with your question and make it clear what exactly you are asking. Many thnks.

Comment: Added a generic sample

Comment: What do you mean by "is it OK"? Does your code work when you try it?

Comment: Is it thread safe or will this cause "race conditions and unexpected side effects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter from perspective of the job. Every job is one scope - meaning that whenever you create a new job, that job will activated wia `CoreBackgroundJobPerformer` that will use `JobActivator` to create a new scope for that job.

So the main job of `BackgroundJobClient` is creating the definition of the job that will later be activated wia Hangfire Server.

You can find more in depth in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883200/6600207)