# Scoped dependencies in Hangfire Job

Tags: .net-core, .net-7.0, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire in .Net 7 app to run a **Fire and Forget job.** In the documentation it says that only Transient or Singleton dependencies are allowed. However docs seem to be **outdated**, since they require use of `JobActivator`, which is no longer needed. I wire in Scoped dependencies inside the job. And those Scoped dependencies even have other Scoped dependencies in use. And it works.

But I have questions about further potential issues:

Will hangfire dispose that scoped object after job finishes? Or will it be leaked into memory? Do I need to manually dispose Scoped dependencies?

I crawled Internet a lot about this issue, but there seems to be either outdated and/or no definitive answer for it.

What made me worry about the issue is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829993/hangfire-dependency-injection-with-net-core)

where it says

> This is implementation is wrong and should not be used. There is a
> reason the job activator has those BeginScope functions. The only way
> to use this implementation here is to pass it the root service
> provider. Which means it is never disposed, meaning every time you
> create a job, you leak all the dependencies that are created.

Comment: Please share the relevant code your question concerns. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Hangfire.NetCore` and registering your hangfire like this :

```
services.AddHangfire(c => c
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseConsole()
    ,new SqlServerStorageOptions()));
```

Then yes , since under the hood `Hangfire.NetCore` uses [`AspNetCoreJobActivator`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/6525aa314f65d1a029863928edf8c9cfc18ec30d/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreJobActivator.cs#L1) that has dependency on `IServiceScopeFactory`. The `BeginScope` method returns `AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope` instance which has dependency on `IServiceScope` which is created scope from 'IServiceScopeFactory'.

If you look into the [`CoreBackgroundJobPerformer`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/main/src/Hangfire.Core/Server/CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.cs) it uses `JobActivator` in `using` statement so everything will be disposed at the end of the using statement.

**So in short every hangfire job is one scope.**